# Ruby on Rails - RSpec - Refactoring a lambda style test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, refactoring

I'm pretty sure I can make this test cleaner, been searching all over but can't crack it. The test passes but I would like to refactor.

```
describe "as an authenticated user that made the offer" do
    before { log_in offering_user; }
    specify { expect { delete :destroy, id: offer.id }.to change(Offer, :count).by(-1) }
    describe "redirect and flash" do
      before { delete :destroy, id: offer.id }
      specify { response.should redirect_to item_path(offer.receiving_item) }
      specify { flash[:success].should_not be_nil }
    end
end
```

See how I have had to make the request twice in the spec? It's forced me to use another describe block too. Ideally I could just make the request in the first `before` block and have something along the lines of

```
it { should change(Offer, :count).by(-1) }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind refactoring your tests to use `expect` syntax ([recommended](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax)), and testing multiple conditions in the same test, you could do the following:

```
describe "as an authenticated user that made the offer" do
  let(:destroying_an_offer) { -> { delete :destroy, id: offer.id } }
  before { log_in offering_user }

  it "destroys offer" do
    expect(destroying_an_offer).to change(Offer, :count).by(-1)
    expect(response).to redirect_to(item_path(offer.receiving_item))
    expect(flash[:success]).to_not be_nil
  end
end
```

The first `expect` will make the `delete` request, and the rest of the `expect`s will operate on the aftermath.

If you want to use the `should` syntax, I don't think you'll be able to avoid making the request multiple times, so it'd be difficult to further refactor them out of your specs.  As a bit of food for thought though, if you wanted to specifically spec out the different aspects of your app that are affected by the request, you could even do `subject` changing for each spec in order to get a singular focused `it` block per spec:

```
describe "as an authenticated user that made the offer" do
  before do
    log_in offering_user
    delete :destroy, id: offer.id
  end

  describe "behaviour" do
    subject { response }
    it { should redirect_to item_path(offer.receiving_item) }
  end

  describe "appearance" do
    subject { flash[:success] }
    it { should_not be_nil }
  end

  describe "result" do
    subject { -> { delete :destroy, id: offer.id } }
    it { should change(Offer, :count).by(-1) }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use implicit subject with lambda notation you can do the following:

```
describe "as an authenticated user that made the offer" do
  before { log_in offering_user }
  subject { -> { delete :destroy, id: offer.id } }
  it { should change {Offer.count}.by(-1) }
end
```

I don't see yet how to dry up this test :)